# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Нужна ли запятая после "если" и можно ли заменить точку с запятой на другой знак

Tags: союзы, деепричастия, точка-с-запятой

И если вы из самых добрых намерений будете убеждать меня в том, как важно ценить свой опыт, уважать свой путь, свои способы; если, говоря все это, не заметите, как мрачнеет моё лицо, то знайте, что я злюсь.

Comment: Насчет остального точно сказать не смогу, но перед *если* запятая не ставится

Comment: "*Убеждать в том, что важно*", а не "*убеждать в том, как важно*". Сравнить: *рассказывать о том, как важно*.

Comment: Втрое "если" желательно на "и" заменить, потому что там по смыслу "и при этом" (вместо "при этом" "говоря всё это"). А при текущей структуре предложение трудно понять, построено неудачно, даже неправильно.

Comment: В том, что важно и в том, как важно — имеют два разных смысла.

Comment: @Серж Да, но нельзя убеждать в том, как важно. = *Убеждать в том, насколько важно.* => *Убеждать в том, в какой степени важно.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В справочнике Д.Э. Розенталя, в разделе [Вариативные знаки препинания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=185#pp185) говорится следующее.
Сопоставим два предложения:

**Был тихий мороз, заря догорала, высоко лежали пуховые снега (Пан.);
Полки ряды свои сомкнули; в кустах рассыпались стрелки; катятся ядра, свищут пули; нависли хладные штыки (П.).**

В подобных случаях возможна вариативность употребления запятой и точки с запятой.

Как видно из примеров, иногда вместо точки с запятой можно поставить запятую, если части сложного предложения более не менее связаны по смыслу.

В вашем примере части сложного предложения достаточно распространены, между ними есть запятые, они разделены на два блока, в этом случае предпочтительно поставить точку с запятой.

Ср.: **Давыдову становилось чуточку грустно оттого, что там теперь многое изменилось; что он теперь уже не сможет ночи напролёт просиживать за чертежами; что теперь о нём, видимо, забыли (Ш.).**

Ср. примеры с однородными членами предложения с относящимися к ним придаточными частями предложений.

**Его уважали за его отличные, аристократические манеры, за слухи о его победах; за то, что он прекрасно одевался и всегда останавливался в лучшем номере лучшей гостиницы; за то, что он вообще хорошо обедал, а однажды даже пообедал с Веллингтоном у Людовика-Филиппа; за то, что он всюду возил с собой настоящий серебряный несессер и походную ванну; за то, что от него пахло какими-то необыкновенными, удивительно «благородными» духами; за то, что он мастерски играл в вист и всегда проигрывал... (Т.)**

[Академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg30.php).

Answer (score 0):

***И если** вы из самых добрых намерений будете убеждать меня в том, как важно ценить свой опыт, уважать свой путь, свои способы; **если,** говоря все это, не заметите, как мрачнеет моё лицо, **то знайте, что я злюсь.***

> Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

**На мой взгляд, не совсем правильно.** Главное предложение относится здесь к блоку сильно распространённых придаточных, **к тому же разделённых таким сильным знаком, как *точка с запятой.*** Перед главным предложением делается удлинённая пауза, и одной запятой перед ним недостаточно. Главное предложение стоит отделить от первой части **запятой и тире.**

Ср. с примером из **[ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)** под ред. Лопатина:

> **§ 126.** В сложноподчиненном предложении ставится **запятая и тире,** если предложение построено в виде периода, который всегда
> делится на две части — произнесенные с повышением и понижением тона
> (запятая и тире ставятся на месте деления): ***Если** зашумела старая
> листва под ногой, **если** закраснелись веточки разные, **если** вербы
> развернулись, **если** заговорили деревья разных пород ароматом своей
> коры, — **то,** значит, есть в березах движение, и нечего портить
> березу* (Пришв.).

Или с примером из **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144&ysclid=ll9add0wms293263374):**

> **§ 40… Запятая и тире** в качестве единого знака ставятся в сложноподчиненном предложении <…> перед главной частью, которой
> предшествует ряд **однородных придаточных**, если подчеркивается
> распадение сложного предложения на две части (перед главной частью
> делается длительная пауза): *Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не
> нам* (Кр.).